# How to Multi Join MySql in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

i'm in need of help for this multi left join in ci4.

here is my MySql script.

```
SELECT
    prod_name,
    cat_name,
    stat_name,
    sup_name,
    cust_name,
    date_borrow,
    date_return
FROM
    tbproduct as a
    LEFT JOIN tbcategory as b ON (b.cat_id=a.prodcat_id)
    LEFT JOIN tbstatus as c ON (c.stat_id=a.prodstat_id)
    LEFT JOIN tbsupplier as d ON (d.sup_id=a.prodsup_id)
    LEFT JOIN tbcustomer as e ON (e.cust_id=a.prodcust_id)
```

the output what i want is like the SELECT.

and here is my script in CodeIgniter 4
i've tried in Model_product.php like this.

```
public function getProduct($id = false)
{
   if($id === false){
        return $this->table('tbproduct')
        ->join('tbcategory', 'tbcategory.cat_id = tbprodcat_id', 'left')
        ->join('tbstatus', 'tbstatus.cat_id = tbprodstat_id', 'left')
        ->join('tbsupplier', 'tbsupplier.sup_id =  tbproduct.prodsup_id', 'left')
        ->join('tbcustomer', 'tbcustomer.cust_id = tbproduct.prodcust_id', 'left')
        ->get()
        ->getResultArray();
    }
```

and it seem i don't have the correct answer from this.
is it in my query in MySql or in the codeigniter 4?

also how to insert to all tables which the value of strings turn into integer value?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `->table('tbproduct')`? If your model is set properly, you don't need to tell in your function which table CI4 should focus.

Comment: already done, many thanks for the respong. here is the finish query.
`if ($id === false) {
            return $this->table('tbproducts')
                ->join('tbcategory', 'tbproduct.prodcat_id = tbcategory.cat_id', 'left')
                ->join('tbstatus', 'tbproduct.prodstat_id = tbstatus.stat_id', 'left')
                ->join('tbsupplier', 'tbproduct.prodsup_id = tbsupplier.sup_id', 'left')
                ->get()
                ->getResultArray();
        }`